# I get error when i login to my project and then go back to the base url

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, session

I'm getting error when  login to my project and then goto the base url. The below is the error which i get

[image]

**My Login page [ see the url ]**

[image]

**After logging in , if i remove the highlighted segments[pls see below image] after which i get the above error**

[image]

I know these error are due to headers so can somebody help me in saying what error am i making in header. An also say how to make good use of session so that the form is to resubmitted when i refresh after logging in. Below are the header codes.

**login header**

```
<?php if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged'])){
    header("location: http://localhost/capacity_planner/login/login_check");
}
?>
```

**admin dashboard[after logging in header]**

```
<?php if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged'])){
    $email = ($this->session->userdata['logged']['email']);
}else{
  header("location: http://localhost/capacity_planner/login"); 
}
?>
```

**controller side**

```
public function login_check(){
            $data['base_url'] = base_url();
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');
            if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == false) {   

                $this->index();

            } else {

               if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged'])) {
                $data['login_bg'] = $this->input->post('login_bg');
                $this->load->view("admin_db", $data);
            } 
            }

function check_database($password){

        $email= $this->input->post('email');

        $user = $this->user->loginCheck($email, $password);

        if($user[1] == 1){
            $result = $this->user->user_details($email);
            if($result != false) {
            $session_data = array(
            'id' => $result[0]->id,
            'email' => $result[0]->cp_email,
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged', $session_data); 
            return true;
            }
        } else{
             $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', $user[0]);
        return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: u have also added the header location in login kindly post that also.

Comment: i've posted above!!

Comment: so what have you done in the login check?

Comment: i've updated/added  the controller above

Comment: I'd recommend extending your base controllers with a login check function rather than using URLs and such.

Comment: ohk then in login_check has the form validation functionality it needs the post request with email password so it goes to index page not the  `header("location: http://localhost/capacity_planner/login/login_check");` other wise it will always goes to else part

Answer (score 0):

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS is caused when strucked up in a conditional **loop**

I assume you want to redirect to admin dashboard if you go to index after logged in..

Try adding these lines in your public function index()

```
public function index(){
        if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged'])) {
                    //admin_db display function eg.redirect('admindashboard');
            }
        else{
           //load your index view 
           this->load->view('your_index_view');
          } 
}
```

or you can check reverse way in admin dashboard function like this

```
public function dashboard(){    
if($this->session->userdata('logged') == ''){
            redirect('index');
            }
            else{

            $this->load->view('dashboard view');        
            }
}
```

This is my assumption.Kindly check it.